# How can I sum 2 integral template arguments and use the result to instantiate another template?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to create something like this:

```
template<int L> 
class FP {
public:
    int n;

    template<int K> 
    FP<L+K> add(FP<K> a) {
        FP<L+K> r;
        r.n = n+a.n;
        return r;
    }

    template<int K> int addS(FP<K> a) {
        return L+K;
    }
};

int main()
{
   FP<1> n1;
   FP<2> n2;
   FP<n1.addS(n2)> n3 = n1.add(n2);
 }
```

I get this from the compiler:

> In function 'int main()':
>
> 19:16: error: call to non-constexpr function 'int FP::addS(FP) [with int K = 2; int L = 1]'
>
> 19:16: error: call to non-constexpr function 'int FP::addS(FP) [with int K = 2; int L = 1]'
>
> 19:17: note: in template argument for type 'int'
>
> 19:22: error: invalid type in declaration before '=' token
>
> 19:33: error: cannot convert 'FP<3>' to 'int' in initialization
>
> 19:19: warning: unused variable 'n3' [-Wunused-variable]
>    In instantiation of 'FP<(L + K)> FP::add(FP) [with int K = 2; int L = 1]':
>
> 19:33:   required from here
>
> 9:5: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]

How do I fix this?

Generally, I want to save the result to the correct variable but don't want to calculate the correct template value.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
FP<n1.addS(n2)>
```

because the result of addS is not a constant expression. You must mark it as one

```
template<int K> constexpr int addS(FP<K> a)
```

Now constexpr functions yield constant expressions only if their arguments are constant expressions too, so n1 and n2 should also be marked as constexpr.

```
constexpr FP<1> n1;
constexpr FP<2> n2;
```

Comment: but now it say: main.cpp:19:10: note: 'n2' was not declared 'constexpr'                                                                                                             
    FP<2> n2;                                                                                                                                                       
          ^

Comment: other solution is also fine.

Comment: `n1` and `n2` should be `constexpr` too.

Comment: I don't understand why n1 and n2 need to be contexpr. The template value is fixed. And also its not working

Comment: "its not working" is no use. In what way? Show us the error.

Answer (score 1):

The simpler would be to use `auto`

```
auto n3 = n1.add(n2);
```

else you have to put missing `constexpr`

```
template<int L> 
class FP {
public:
    int n;

    template<int K> 
    FP<L+K> add(FP<K> a) const {
        FP<L+K> r;
        r.n = n+a.n;
        return r;
    }

    template<int K> constexpr static int addS(FP<K> a) {
        return L+K;
    }
};

int main()
{
   constexpr FP<1> n1;
   constexpr FP<2> n2;
   FP<n1.addS(n2)> n3 = n1.add(n2);
 }
```

Comment: Great solution. wasn't awere of this. auto should work on all compilers?

Comment: @nir `auto` should work on all compilers supports C++11.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either an `auto`:

```
auto n3 = n1.add(n2);
```

Or slightly change the declaration of `addS` as it follows:

```
template<int K>
static constexpr int addS(FP<K> &) {
    return L+K;
}
```

As mentioned by @Jarod42.
Otherwise you can use also a `decltype`:

```
decltype(n1.add(n2)) n3 = n1.add(n2);
```

Or a `constexpr` support function:

```
template<int I, int J>
constexpr int f(FP<I> &, FP<J> &) {
    return I+J;
}

// ...

FP<f(n1, n2)> n3 = n1.add(n2);
```

If you don't want to change the definition of `addS`.